# Push a dataframe on dynamodb without having duplicates errors

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, dataframe, amazon-dynamodb

I want to put in AWS DynamoDb this dataframe :

```
data = {'primary_key': [1, 1, 2, 3],
        'piece': [2, 3, 4, 5],
        'name': ['avion', 'train', 'voiture', 'velo'],
        'year_sort_key': [2024, 2024, 2024, 2024],
        'month': [2, 2, 2, 2]}
```

When I put the data dataframe, I have a duplicates because We have primary_key with value=1 and piece with value 2,3
I want to save name in string don't want list or tuple

I use this code to put df on dynamodb s3 :

```
 wr.dynamodb.put_df(
            df=data,
            table_name=table
        )
```

the output I want is :

```
       primary_key     piece        name   year_sort_key  month
0             1           2        'avion'    2024         2
1             1           3        'train'    2024         2
2             2           4        'voiture'  2024         2
3             3           5        'velo'     2024         2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dynamo feature called sortKey!
By configuring **piece** as sortkey you will be able to use the table like you described.

For that, you need to configure the sort key in **Table details** while creating a new dynamo table:
[image]

Using the given code, I had to convert data to DataFrame to use in **put_df** function and my code ended like this:

```py
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd

data = {'primary_key': [1, 1, 2, 3],
        'piece': [2, 3, 4, 5],
        'name': ['avion', 'train', 'voiture', 'velo'],
        'year_sort_key': [2024, 2024, 2024, 2024],
        'month': [2, 2, 2, 2]}

wr.dynamodb.put_df(
    df=pd.DataFrame(data),
    table_name='table_test'
)
```

This is the output in DynamoDB:
[image]

Hope this helps!